# Cocoa: How to create implement scroll view from scratch?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm successfully modified the position of window buttons in cocoa tab bar app. But from macOS Big Sur, The collectionView inside the scroll view has size issue. It's not go up above the bottom of the buttons. I think it's because of OS bug.

**In normal:**

[image]

**In full screen:**

[image]

**View hierarchy:**

[image]

**Without NSScrollView:**

[image]

**Code for the collectionView:**

```
private lazy var collectionView: NSCollectionView = {
        
        let collectionView = NSCollectionView()
        let layout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        
        let scrollView = BarLessScrollView()
        scrollView.documentView = collectionView
        self.titleBar.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleBar.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleBar.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleBar.rightAnchor),
            scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleBar.leftAnchor),
        ])
         
        collectionView.register(Item.self, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "Item"))
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.isSelectable = true
        collectionView.allowsEmptySelection = true
        collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        
        collectionView.backgroundColors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.9387472272, green: 0.9387472272, blue: 0.9387472272, alpha: 1)]
        return collectionView
    }()
```

The NSToolbar is perfect. But, I can't change the height of the NSToolBar.

Now, I've only option to implement scrollview from scratch to solve this problem.

Can you please give me an outline?